# How can I create a "personality-test" using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is both a request for existing open-source modules, as well as the "architecture".  The data-gathering part (asking questions) looks like can be done using surveyor or wizard gems.

The part I need help on is...how do you "weight" or "score" the answers to come up with the "personality"?  For example, Myers-Briggs type tests ask multiple questions and then describe one of 16 personalities.

I want to limit my outcomes to four, but I'm not sure how.  The standard "If you scored 10-16, you're a rockstar; if you scored 5-9, go home" I don't think quite works this same way?

This is more of a "design" question, so if there's a better place I can ask it, let me know, but it feels that people may know programmatically how in rails to do this kind of simplified expert-system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have four personality types, and each user's test creates a rank for *each* of these types.  (e.g. By the end of the test, the user will have a score of 50 for Type-A, a score for 86 for Type-B, a score of 34 for Type-C, and a score of 60 for Type-D)  The user is designated by whichever personality type has the highest score.  (e.g. Type-B)

Each question in the personality test is multiple choice.  Every answer contributes a certain amount to one or more of the personality types.  (e.g. On question 1, an answer of "D" will contribute 5 points to Type-A, 3 points to Type-B, and 0 points to Type-C and Type-D.)

Each answer for each question would have a 4-digit `value` attribute, indicating how the math on your back end should be carried out.  For instance:

```
<input type="radio" name="question_one" value="5400" />
<input type="radio" name="question_one" value="3211" />
<input type="radio" name="question_one" value="5608" />
<input type="radio" name="question_one" value="9006" />
```

Here's how you might handle the back end in Ruby on Rails.  First, you have a User object named `@user`, which has four fields, type_a, type_b, type_c, type_d, indicating how well the User aligns with each of the four personality types.  In your User model, include a method like this:

```
def process_answer(value)
  self.type_a += value[0].chr.to_i
  self.type_b += value[1].chr.to_i
  self.type_c += value[2].chr.to_i
  self.type_d += value[3].chr.to_i
```

In your controller, pass the form data to your User instance:

```
  @user.process_answer(params[:question_one])
```

If the user selects the second option for question_one (corresponding to a value of "3211"), then his personality profile will increase 3 pts for type-A, 2 pts for type-B, 1 pt for type-C, and 1 pt for type-D.

Comment: what is a good way to strucure the "math" in ruby (or rails)?

Comment: In Rails, each User object has four integer fields (one for each personality type).  Every time the user submits form information, his/ User object's four integer fields get updated.  e.g. `if params[:question1] == "a"; type_a += 4; end`

Comment: (That's not a great example, since it doesn't lend itself to scaling, but it's hard to offer more without actually designing the system oneself.)

Comment: I think that's the idea, but as you see, it looks like it could get complicated beyond three questions....it doesn't need to be complex, but just wondering if there's a good approach...along these lines...?

Comment: I can see what you mean if, for example, you have 10 questions per page, how do you handle the back-end programming so that it's not long and convoluted?  Well, you can put most of the work in the front end (where questions and answers are getting the programmer's attention individually anyway).  For example, say you have 10 questions on a page, each with four possible choices, implemented with a radio button.  The radio buttons will each have a name corresponding to their question (so that answers under a single question will be mutually exclusive) but the values they give will contain...

Comment: ...all the info you need.  For example, you might give each answer a 4-digit number for its value. Each digit corresponds to 1 of the 4 personality types. Question 1 Answer 1 might have an attribute `value=4301`, which indicates to the back end how much it needs to add to each of the 4 personality types for the current User object: add 4 to TypeA, 3 to TypeB, 0 to TypeC, 1 to TypeD.

Comment: ...So on a page of 10 questions, you get 10 values (10 4-digit numbers) passed to the back end.  The back end doesn't have to know what the questions and answers are; it just performs a simple, uniform operation on each of the 10 answers.

Comment: How do I make that calculation to parse based on the digit, this is pretty good....

Comment: The number (value) is going to be passed in as a String, so you can isolate it by character.  In ruby on rails, you'd do something like this: `params[:question_one][0].chr.to_i`.  This gives you the number at the first digit (index 0).  The `.chr` is necessary because otherwise you'd get a character code, not a character.  The `.to_i` is necessary so that the character is converted into its numerical value (so you can do math with it).

Comment: The second digit would be `params[:question_one][1].chr.to_i`; the third would be `params[:question_one][2].chr.to_i`; and the fourth would be `params[:question_one][3].chr.to_i`.

Comment: ...It's hard to read down here, so I updated my answer above with some code snippets.  Give those a look.

Comment: this seems like a pretty good way to go....how would I then determine what the right "range" is for the answers?  The thresholds would need to be static, right?  In other words >60 for A means an A...etcetera...

Comment: If you use thresholds to determine which of the 4 types is the winner, yes, they should be static.  But I think it would be less restrictive, when creating your test questions and answers, to not include thresholds but just rank personality types by order of score.  Whichever of the four types has the highest score is the result.  To spice it up, you can have your program keep an eye out for any runners-up which have a score greater than or equal to 80% of the winning personality type's score.